# Values increasing when JOIN Statement is added

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have been having some difficulties with this issue for a few days and I cannot figure it out.

(Running this is Bigquery)

For a marketing client, I am trying to obtain impressions and clicks per advertiser.

p_impressions has all the impressions data, including IDs Campaign_ID, Advertiser_ID
p_click has all the click data, including IDs Campaign_ID, Advertiser_ID
match_table_campaigns has campaign data: Campaign_ID, Campaign Name

(essentially my simple goal is to get the count of impressions and clicks and match it to the Campaign table so that I can see the name of the campaign and not just the ID.

When I run a query using UNION all for both the Impression and Click tables, using only the IDS, all the numbers match my platform and everything looks great.

However, when I insert a JOIN (I've tried all of them) to include the name of the campaign, all the metrics of Impressions and click seems to increase and I cannot seem to get the correct numbers anymore.

```
with combinedDeliveryData AS (
SELECT
  FORMAT_DATETIME("%F",DATETIME(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS( CAST(SUBSTR(CAST( Event_Time AS String),0,LENGTH(CAST( Event_Time AS String)) - 3) AS INT64 )),"America/Toronto")) AS Date,
  Impression_ID,
  DBM_Advertiser_ID,
  Campaign_ID,
  Ad_ID,
  Rendering_ID,
  Event_Type,
  Advertiser_ID,
FROM
  CampaignManager.p_impression
UNION ALL
SELECT
  FORMAT_DATETIME("%F",DATETIME(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS( CAST(SUBSTR(CAST( Event_Time AS String),0,LENGTH(CAST( Event_Time AS String)) - 3) AS INT64 )),"America/Toronto")) AS Date,
  Impression_ID,
  DBM_Advertiser_ID,
  Campaign_ID,
  Ad_ID,
  Rendering_ID,
  Event_Type,
  Advertiser_ID,
FROM
  CampaignManager.p_click)
  
SELECT cpg.Campaign_ID, cpg.Campaign,data.Date,COUNT(case data.Event_Type when 'VIEW' then 1 else null end) AS Impressions
FROM match_table_campaigns AS cpg
LEFT JOIN combinedDeliveryData AS data ON cpg.Campaign_ID = data.Campaign_ID
WHERE cpg.Advertiser_ID = "4739279"
GROUP BY 3,1,2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am not sure what I am missing.

AS a note, here is what works without the JOIN

```
SELECT
  Impression_ID,
  Event_Time,
  DBM_Advertiser_ID,
  Campaign_ID,
  Ad_ID,
  Rendering_ID,
  Event_Type,
  Advertiser_ID
FROM
  CampaignManager.p_impression
UNION ALL
SELECT
  Impression_ID,
  Event_Time,
  DBM_Advertiser_ID,
  Campaign_ID,
  Ad_ID,
  Rendering_ID,
  Event_Type,
  Advertiser_ID
FROM
  CampaignManager.p_click)
SELECT FORMAT_DATETIME("%F",DATETIME(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS( CAST(SUBSTR(CAST( clicks.Event_Time AS String),0,LENGTH(CAST( clicks.Event_Time AS String)) - 3) AS INT64 )),"America/Toronto")) AS exposureDate,clicks.Campaign_ID,COUNT(case Event_Type when 'VIEW' then 1 else null end) AS Impressions,COUNT(case Event_Type when 'CLICK' then 1 else null end) AS Clicks
FROM 
combinedDeliveryData AS clicks
WHERE clicks.Campaign_ID = "4739279"
GROUP BY 1,2
```

NEW ISSUE:
Ive added the following code and things looked great

```
  this_is_deduplicated AS (
    SELECT x.*
    FROM (
      SELECT Campaign_ID, ARRAY_AGG(a LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] x
      FROM combinedDeliveryData a
      GROUP BY 1
    ) 
  )

LEFT JOIN this_is_deduplicated AS data ON cpg.Campaign_ID = data.Campaign_ID
```

Getting all my values, and they are acurrate.  I am now running into a nother issue where I have to join a final table, but the solution above is not working for it.

Values in new table:
Date
Campaign_ID
Activity_ID

I need to now join this last table so that for each Date, I get the COUNT of Activity_ID As Conversiions.

My Final table should be:

Advertiser, Campaign, Impressions, Clicks, Conversions (As above)

Comment: If the numbers increase when joining, that would suggest that there are multiple records in `match_table_campaigns` with the same `Campaign_ID`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm almost sure the cause is having multiple identical `campaign_id` in the `combinedDeliveryData` table.

Make sure there's only one id per campaign before doing the join. With something like:

```sql
WITH [...], 
  this_is_deduplicated AS (
    SELECT x.*
    FROM (
      SELECT Campaign_ID, ARRAY_AGG(a LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] x
      FROM combinedDeliveryData a
      GROUP BY 1
    ) 
  )
```

And `JOIN` against that as in:

```sql
LEFT JOIN this_is_deduplicated AS data ON cpg.Campaign_ID = data.Campaign_ID
```

instead of

`LEFT JOIN combinedDeliveryData AS data ON cpg.Campaign_ID = data.Campaign_ID`

or a shorter

```sql
LEFT JOIN this_is_deduplicated AS data USING(Campaign_ID)
```

Comment: I suspect this as well, but I cannot figure out how to solve for it.  I've never used : ARRAY_AGG(a LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)], would I have to include that in my with query for combinedDeliveryData or do I include that in my second query where I join?  I did try to add it at the end of the 2nd query but got incorrect results again...if you could help based on my current query that would be amazing

Comment: I made some changes based on the above comment. Basically replace the existing joining table with this one

Comment: Ok, I just added this and did a select * because I wanted to understand what this outout and I get it now - the issue im getting now is that in my select statement data.date doesn't exist anymore as it is now assigned ot the dedupliated table

Comment: OK, i had to re-do some of the other code and got this to work with this method...THank you very much.

Comment: I think I know what you mean... try the additional `x.*` I added now

Comment: Hi there, wondering if there was a chance you could continue to assist me?  Your help worked before but it didn't fix a 3rd issue I now have...updated the ask above. @Felipe Hoffa

Comment: If this worked, please accept and upvote answer. Happy to have me and the community look at a new question too!

Comment: Understood...Answer was aready accepted ;) I just upvoted and will post new qustion thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may need to join on `campaign` and `campaign_id`. Provided you sample query below

```
select
    t1.date,
    t1.campaign_id,
    t1.campaign,
    sum(case when t1.event = 'view' then 1 else 0 end) as impressions,
    sum(case when t2.event = 'click' then 1 else 0 end) as clicks
from table1 as t1
left join table2 as t2
on t1.campaign = t2.campaign
and on t1.campaign_id = t2.campaign_id

where advertiser_id = '12345'
group by
    t1.campaign_id,
    t1.campaign,
    t1.date
```

Comment: Campaign doesn't exisit in both tables, only Campaign_ID